# How to find one of my accelerated mobile pages that is cached by Google already?

Tags: google-search, cache, google-cache, amp

For AMP (Accelerated mobile pages) pages, I know about the API to find out if a URL is cached or not.   However, I'm having trouble finding one that is cached.   I need to find a cached AMP URL to write/test other code against that API.

My AMP URLs don't seem to appear near the top of the search results so I'm  having difficulty finding a single one which has already been cached.   The only way I know is to check one by one, but maybe there something I can add to search query to find my cached pages?

Edit: I expect none or very few pages are cached already, that's why the question.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have an API to find the cached page, why can't you find the cached page?

Comment: I don't write code yet, and expect most/all results will be false, as pages not cached yet by Google. Need something to test code. This is the way I coding - write-test-and-again-loop.

Comment: What do you mean? You test your code by running it to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, and seems none of very few pages already cached.

Comment: In google, you can type `site:example.com` to find all of the pages on your domain that have been indexed by Google, which may be helpful.

Comment: There are no tools or services to do exactly what I want in question. @MaximillianLaumeister your comment are simple and most useful, add it as answer if you wish.

Comment: Not an an answer but usefull tool, make cache url from own hosted url: https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google generally caches the pages that it indexes, unless the site owner specifically requests Google not to (e.g. by using the [`NOARCHIVE` meta tag](https://searchengineland.com/google-explains-the-noindex-nofollow-noarchive-nosnippet-meta-tags-10595)).

One way of checking if your web pages are indexed by Google is to type `site:example.com` into Google Search. This will show you all the pages on your site that Google has indexed.